# How to pass dropdownbox select value to a controller in asp.net mvc using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewresult

I have the following `DropDownListFor` generated by razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSize, Model.AvailableSizes, "Select Size", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id ="availablesize" })
```

I want to pass the selected value of `DropDownList` to a controller `ViewResult` method:

```
public ViewResult Index(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new CartIndexViewModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                Cart = cart,
            });
        }
```

Help please!

Comment: Did you get it resolve? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes use a hidden field for and send it to the controller